# Can i write data to firebase without making an event?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to save data to firebase on onstart() method but it is not working.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Transaction payment=new Transaction("merchant","user","1000","live");
    mDatabase.child("transctions").child("2").setValue(payment);
}
```

Comment: i found the solution  just Add  ->  DatabaseReference mDatabase;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just we have to initialize the Database reference in the onstart().

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
DatabaseReference mDatabase;
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Transaction payment=new Transaction("merchant","user","1000","live");
mDatabase.child("transctions").child("2").setValue(payment);
}
```